# HTML Viewer error "Err cache Miss" using ADB

Tags: android, android-webview, adb

Why the below command returns the result in the attached picture ? and how to solve it ?

```
 adb shell am start -n com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity -d "https://www.google.com" -a VIEW -t "text/html"
```

[image]

Comment: Have you declared Internet permission in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```